# How to calculate max values in a dataframe column while removing duplicates in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

[image]
I have a dataset containing hourly temperatures for a year. So, I have 24 entries for each day (temp for every hour) and I want to find out the 5 days with highest temp. I am aware of nlargest() function to find out 5 max values but those values happen to be on a single day only. How do I find out the 5 max values but on different days?

I tried using nlargest() and .loc() but could not find the solution. Please help.

I have attached what the dataset looks like.

Comment: can you provide a sample of your code?

Comment: Please don't post images of your data. Instead make a copy (of a sample) and post it in a code block. Images are hard to copy'n'past.

Comment: Did you try to `resample()` your data with the frequency of one day and keep the `max()`? Then `nlargest()` will return the data you are looking for.

Comment: Noted. Will post sample codes next time. It is solved now.. just had to use groupby() to filter it out daywise. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to get the max per group with [`groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) then find the top 5 with [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html)

```
df.groupby(['year','month','day'])['temp'].max().nlargest(5)
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved it! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby

An example would be

```
max_5_temps = df.groupby('date_column')['temperature_column'].max().nlargest(5)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I just had to put the date as (['month','day']) in groupby.